# Circle Geometry - Proving Question

Tags: geometry, circles

Suppose $C$ is any point on a circle, above a diameter $AB$.  $P$ and $Q$ are points on the minor arcs $\widehat{AC}$ and $\widehat{BC}$. Prove that $$\angle APC + \angle CQB = \frac32\pi$$
Currently I drew the shape $APCQB$ to be a pentagon inside the circle and let $\angle APC =\alpha, \angle CQB=\beta$. Tried using the diameter to create right angles to generate an equation using angle sum = $3\pi$, tried introducing cyclic quads too, the diagram became too full and I was not getting anywhere. Any help please?

Comment: If $C$ is on the diameter, what is meant by "arcs $\widehat{AC}$ and $\widehat{BC}$"?

Comment: AB is the diameter, I drew C on top of the diameter, P to the left of C and Q to the right of C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $O$ is the center of the circle.

An inscribed angle on a circle, from some point on the major arc between two points, is half the size of the central angle to the same two points (see, e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem).)
On the other hand, an inscribed angle from a point in the minor arc between two points is the supplement of this, i.e. $\pi$ minus half the central angle. (see e.g. [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/circleinscribed.html).)
For instance, $\angle APC = \pi - \frac 1 2 \angle AOC$. Also, $\angle CQB = \pi - \frac 1 2 \angle COB$.

Of course, $\angle AOC + \angle COB = \pi$.
So $\angle APC + \angle CQB = 2 \pi - \frac 1 2 \pi$.